# Hyperspectral Image + Field Data

Tags: data, remote-sensing

There is plenty of remote sensing datasets out there, but I haven't been able to find one along with field data. Particularly I am looking for airborne hyperspectral images that have field data identifying plant species as well as their coordinates in the image.

Even if a dataset is from one organization and image from another, that works too.

Answer (score 1):

the link http://dataservices.gfz-potsdam.de/portal/ gives you an overview of some available datasets from research institutions. Use the datacenter-filter "EnMap" (which is a German satellite mission) to see only data from hyperspectral flight campaigns. You might need to register for receiving some data depending on the institution providing.

You will probably not get field data for the respective raster data, but you should try to create it by yourself with auxilliary data like GoogleEarth, OpenStreetMap or Survey Data from a governmental institution.